# Compass (Sass): Watch Multiple Projects

Tags: sass, compass-sass, watch, compass

I'm using Compass, the Sass framework. If I want to watch multiple projects, is this the right way to do it?

```
compass watch /path/to/project1/ /path/to/project2/ /path/to/project3/
```

Comment: Have you tried use grunt for this? I think will be more powerful and easy

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to open new terminal windows per project then enter your commands.

This enables each command to be isolated to a particular window and & when you compile your sass you will have a log for each project.

Comment: How does one get to view this log?

Comment: The log is the terminal window, it will tell you when its compiled and any errors in compiling